# API call script fails in cron job but works fine when run manually

Tags: python, cron

API call script fails in cron job but works fine when run manually.
My Python script is making a call to  https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/rest/v1/schema
The error I get is:

> Request failed: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk', port=445): Max retries exceeded with url: /webapi/rest/v1/schema (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0j0iefhfnfj9>, 'Connection to stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))

I have tried increasing timeout but it didn't make a difference. Cron jobs that don't involve making API call work fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import json
import requests
import os


url = 'https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/rest/v1/schema'

# Set your API key in the environment variable
os.environ['APIKey'] = 'myapikey'

#I have also tried this without setting environment variable
#api_key='myapikey'

# Get the API key from the environment variable
api_key = os.environ['APIKey']
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'APIKey': api_key}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    print(response)
    # Process the response...
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("Request failed:", e)
```

My cron job

```
42 18 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/bin/bash/statxplore_api.py
```

Things I have tried:

Set environment variables,
Checked file permissions to ensure it can be executed,
Tested network conn by pinging to https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding proxies to my script. The issue occurred because my user has proxy installed under my profile but contab does not.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
import requests
import os


# Define your proxy server
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://yourproxy:0303',
    'https': 'http://yourproxy:0303'
}


url = 'https://stat-xplore.dwp.gov.uk/webapi/rest/v1/schema'

# Set your API key in the environment variable
os.environ['APIKey'] = 'myapikey'

# Get the API key from the environment variable
api_key = os.environ['APIKey']
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'APIKey': api_key}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=30)
    print(response)
    # Process the response...
except requests.RequestException as e:
    print("Request failed:", e)
```

To find out what proxies are in use you can run the code below

```
import os

proxy_env_vars = ['http_proxy', 'https_proxy']

# Check for proxy settings
for var in proxy_env_vars:
    proxy_val = os.getenv(var)
    if proxy_val:
        print(f"{var}: {proxy_val}")
    else:
        print(f"{var}: Not set")
```